# Add html source to PDF field with Java

Tags: java, html-pdf

I'm trying to create a PDF from a template in my backend and then serve it to the user when it needs to download it. The only problem that I have is that one of the fields in that template must have HTML source in it and must be rendered. Is there any way to add HTML source in that field and render it ? I am currently using PDFBox.

Comment: I suspect you mean XHTML for richtext. This is done with `setRichTextValue()`. Rendering these (I assume you mean create the appearance stream from there) is not supported.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Do you know weather if I return the pdf as embedded in an html page then will that field be rendered ?

Comment: Never mind the previous comment. Do you know any other tool that can serve this purpose ? Thanks.

Comment: 1) if with PDF.js (firefox) then no (don't know about Chrome), 2) no.